# Can't scroll collapsable fixed nav list

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've created a fixed navbar (inspired by Twitter Bootstrap). Because my navh as quite alot of links within it, I've decided to make the mobile level of the nav list fixed height and scroll the overflow-y. All seemed fine when testing it in Google Chrome using the responsive tools. But, when I checked it live on an actual mobile device (iPhone 4), when I try to scroll the nav, it scrolls the page instead.

At first I thought adding a z-index to the nav would fix it, but it didn't.

What CSS do I need to add to ensure that when a user scrolls the nav element it scrolls it instead of the page?

Here is a JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/n1g72opt/

HTML:

```
<header>
  <div class="nav-show-btn">Toggle</div>
  <nav class="show">
    <ul><li><a href="javascript:;" data-route="">Users</a>
    <ul>

      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 2</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 3</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 4</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 5</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 6</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 7</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 2</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 3</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 4</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 5</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 6</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 7</a></li>  
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 6</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 7</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 2</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 3</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 4</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 5</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 6</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 7</a></li>  
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 6</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 7</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 2</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 3</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 4</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 5</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 6</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 7</a></li>  
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 6</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 7</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 2</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 3</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 4</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 5</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 6</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 7</a></li>  
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 6</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 7</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 2</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 3</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 4</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 5</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 6</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 7</a></li>  
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 6</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 7</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 2</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 3</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 4</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 5</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 6</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 7</a></li>  
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 6</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 7</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 2</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 3</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 4</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 5</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 6</a></li>   
      <li><a href="javascript:;">Link 7</a></li>  


    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam condimentum et orci in sagittis. Maecenas laoreet libero id enim congue ornare. Integer ac venenatis leo, et placerat libero. Nunc eu porta justo. Praesent imperdiet turpis ut congue suscipit. Fusce molestie vulputate est. Nam at facilisis nunc. Vivamus tempus eu lacus et
```

CSS:

```
header {
    background: #3b3f44;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
}
.nav-show-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

header nav.show {
    display: block !important;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 80px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: i think the nav element scroll is scrolling the nav element only in your https://jsfiddle.net/n1g72opt/ or i can't get what actually is the problem

Comment: @SajadKaruthedath That is the desired effect. However, this doesn't work on mobile devices. Instead, it scrolls the page behind the nav thus making it impossible to scroll to the last items in the nav.

Comment: Do you just want the navbar to scroll even when it reaches the last item on scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;`  and in my case i need add `height` also.

Set it only when you loading page on mobile phone, use media query like;

```
@media (min-width:320px)  {
/* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */ 
    header nav.show {
            display: block !important;
            max-height: calc(100vh - 80px);
            height: 200px;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            width: 100%;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; // mobile safari
        }
}
```

Comment: a fixed height did the trick along with the mobile safari bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try set ul element to

> overflow: scroll
>   maybe can solf this!

Comment: Make your answers more detailed and use correct syntax highlighting !

Answer (score 0):

You can lock body element on clicking **Toggle** button in-order to avoid body content scrolling until the navBar panel is open.

```
$('.nav-show-btn').on('click', function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('menuOpen');      // Lock Body layer
    $('header > nav').toggleClass('show') // open navbar
});
```

> **jsFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/ShirishDhotre/zt8LhoL8/1/